# If else null values in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Using c# winforms and sqlite

I want to insert from the dataset into my database. The columns are Name, Start Date, End Date. The date and End Date columns' data are all in the wrong format, M/dd/yyyy so I am converting it with `string startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(startdatetime).ToString("dd/M/yyyy");`  The problem is that there are null values in the Start Date and End Date columns so I can't convert everything without checking for null cells first. So I'm not sure what to put for the query because if the cell is empty, inserting startdatetime will put it in the wrong format, whereas inserting startdate will cause an error.
I plan on changing it to be more secure and protecting against sqlinjection after I'm done.

```
        string startdatetime = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Start Date"].Value.ToString();
        string enddatetime = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["End Date"].Value.ToString();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value as string))
                {
                    string txtQuery = "insert into CertDB(DateAttended, EndDate) values ('" + startdatetime + "', '" + enddatetime + "')";
                    ExecuteQuery(txtQuery);
                }
                else
                {
                    string startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(startdatetime).ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
                    string enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(enddatetime).ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
                    string expiry = Convert.ToDateTime(expirytime).ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
                    string txtQuery = "insert into CertDB(DateAttended, EndDate) values ('" + startdate + "', '" + enddate + "')";
                    ExecuteQuery(txtQuery);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: not getting what you are tring to do here. but try like `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(startdatetime) ? DBNull.value : Convert.ToDateTime(startdatetime).ToString("dd/M/yyyy");`

Comment: I can convert it already. Converted variable is startdate whereas the date variable before conversion is startdatetime. I want to insert startdatetime into my database but I can't do it without checking for null cells first because I can't convert null strings

Comment: it's throwing error because of `ToString()`.
Instead use `Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Start Date"].Value)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
string startdatetime = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Start Date"].Value);
string enddatetime = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["End Date"].Value);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(startdatetime)) startdatetime = Convert.ToDateTime(startdatetime).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(enddatetime)) enddatetime = Convert.ToDateTime(enddatetime).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

string txtQuery = "insert into CertDB(DateAttended, EndDate) values ('" + startdatetime + "', '" + enddatetime + "')";

ExecuteQuery(txtQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.ToString()` won't handle `null` so have to use `Convert.ToString()`

```
        string startdatetime = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Start Date"].Value);
        string enddatetime = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["End Date"].Value);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value as string))
                {
                    string txtQuery = "insert into CertDB(DateAttended, EndDate) values ('" + startdatetime + "', '" + enddatetime + "')";
                    ExecuteQuery(txtQuery);
                }
                else
                {
                    string startdate = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(startdatetime) ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(startdatetime).ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
        string enddate = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(enddatetime) : DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(enddatetime).ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
        string expiry = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(expirytime) ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(expirytime).ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
        string txtQuery = "insert into CertDB(DateAttended, EndDate) values ('" + startdate + "', '" + enddate + "')";
        ExecuteQuery(txtQuery);
                }
            }
        }
```

Again `DateAttended` and `EndDate` column should be `nullable` in `DataBase`.
you can also read more about `.ToString()` and `Convert.ToString()`